# Como gerar um par de chaves RSA no Windows 10?

Tags: golang, jwt, rsa

Estou tentando utilizar o jwt, mais especificamente o [jwt para go](https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go), porém preciso gerar um par de chaves (uma publica e uma privada) RSA, tentei gerar pelo puttygen mas dã erro de `Key must be PEM encoded PKCS1 or PKCS8 private key`. Também tentei o openSSL mas ele não é reconhecido pelo Windows. Existe algo para Windows 10 para gerar RSA?

Comment: Recentemente eu tive um problema de como gerar chaves rsa para serem válidas para fazer a validação com o jwt. Eu consegui obter o resultado que queria. Segue o link do projeto. [Heimdall](https://github.com/rafaelgfirmino/heimdall/blob/master/key/key.go)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go possui uma ferramenta para você gerar as chaves. Abra o Terminal de comando e faça o seguinte:

```
> cd %GOROOT%\src\crypto\tls
> go run generate_cert.go --host localhost --ca true

//Substitua C:\ pelo local onde você quer que os arquivos fiquem
> move %GOROOT%\src\crypto\tls\cert.pem C:\cert.pem
> move %GOROOT%\src\crypto\tls\key.pem C:\key.pem
```

Agora, no seu código go, basta fazer o seguinte (Não tratei os erros para simplificar o exemplo):

```
//Substitua C:\ para o local onde estão os arquivos, caso você os tenha mudado de lugar
keyPEM, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("C:\key.pem")
privateKey, _ = jwt.ParseRSAPrivateKeyFromPEM(keyPEM)
certPEM, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("C:\cert.pem")
publicKey, _ = jwt.ParseRSAPublicKeyFromPEM(certPEM)

t := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.GetSigningMethod("RS256"), jwt.MapClaims{
    //Suas Claims
})

signedToken, err := t.SignedString(signKey)
//Etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

O JWT suporta ECDSA (e acho que também EdDSA), que acredito que seja melhor do que RSA, devido ao seu tamanho menor.

Mas, se quiser gerar uma chave poderia usar o próprio Golang, ele tem as seguintes funções criptográficas:

- `rsa.GenerateKey`.
- `x509.MarshalPKCS8PrivateKey`
- `pem.EncodeToMemory`

Que acredito que sejam suficientes para isso.

---

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/x509"
    "fmt"
    "encoding/pem"
)

func main() {
    key, err := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, 4092)
    if err != nil {
        panic("Error")
    }

    pkcs, err := x509.MarshalPKCS8PrivateKey(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic("Error")
    }

    pem := pem.EncodeToMemory(
        &pem.Block{
            Type:  "RSA PRIVATE KEY",
            Bytes: pkcs,
        })

    fmt.Println(string(pem))
}
```

> Isso precisa de GO 1.10, ou use `MarshalPKCS1PrivateKey` que é suportado em versões anteriores.